# columns dereferencing in SharePoint's calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-webservice

I want to use the simple formula:

```
="FIX_" & [ID]
```

The issue with this formula occurs when I confirm the calculated function, the formula appears to revert back to:

```
="FIX_" & ID
```

The problem is now that these are no longer referencing the [ID] column so the result returns

```
"FIX_"
```

for all records. This does work for the first record entered but any other subsequent entries display this error.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Can you mark your question as answered... it keeps popping up in the Unanswered lists; lets keep StackOverflow structured, tnx

Comment: hello Danny Engelman,
I apologize for forgetting to mark this as answered, this has now been corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you only want to display the link in a VIEW.

You can then use HTML/JavaScvript in a Calculated Column to extract the correct ID from the HTML TR table row
and create the href attribute.

Create a Calculated Columns, **and** set the datatype to Number!

Paste the Formula (as is, including & characters, line breaks will be ignored):

```
="<div ""style=text-align:left""><a><img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
&"var row=this;while(row.tagName!='TR'){row=row.parentNode;}"
&"var ID=row.id.split(',')[1];"
&"this.parentNode.href='v://database//FIX_'+ID;"
&"}"">database folder</a></div>"
```

Note: the outer div is added because a Number column is aligned to the Right.

This only works in VIEWS! Not on FORMS!

Comment: hi Danny,
after spending about an hour fiddling around I think I have found a solution and this works!
some key things to note in case anyone comes here...
Danny included breaks in the calculated string (the &" at the start of the line".
I didnt realize why so I removed them but this is wrong! you need them to prevent the string being too long however you can concatenate many strings together.
additionally, this formula likely wont work as is, you need to know some javascript and html DOM traversal to do this properly but its not too difficult.

Comment: Yes, you can only place 255 characters in a SharePoint string "xyz" and you have to concatenate them with either the CONCATENATE function or the & shorthand. The total number of characters in the whole Calculacted Column can not exceed 4000 characters... be aware this includes all the content from other columns you reference, so if you have 2 columns of 2001 characters you can not combine the result in a third column

Answer (score 1):

The [ ] notation has got nothing to do with it.. [ ] are only required if fieldnames contain spaces.. As you experienced SharePoint will strip those [ ] on save.

#### why ID is not listed as a usable Field for Formulas

You can **not** use the ID in a calculated column because on first Item creation the Calculated Column Formula is processed **before** the item is written to the database and gets its ID.

**Thus ID is 0 for newly created items**

When an Item is changed/updated the ID is correctly populated and used with the correct value in Formulas.

Work-around is to create a Workflow (which runs after Item creation) that  gets the ID and writes it to another field, and use that in your Formula

or have the workflow changes something else in any field so an item update is forced; reading the Title and write it back in the same field will do.

Comment: thank you for this information however unfortunately I am not able to do this as we do not have sharepoint designer, using only the poor features of the web side of Sharepoint. This means we are unable to create a workflow and the ones we do have are related to approval.
The last solution I can think of doing is to do it using Javascript on the page load. The reason we want this is because each record should have a folder whose location is something like... 
"V://database/FIX_[ID]"
unfortunately, this means either we need to update the record OR manually type it in each time

Comment: Do you want to display it in a View? You can stuff Javascript in a Calculated Column. See http://ViewMaster365.com/#/How   In the Create Your Own section  there are examples on how to get the ID.. you can then built your link with javascript code and display it in the View

Comment: yea the reason to see it in the view is because the ease to get to the folder related to that record, i will have a look into this! thanks!