# Sharepoint calculated field long time to calculate

Tags: sharepoint

I have made a SharePoint list that has a calculated field that is used as a unique identifier for each item. The field is calculated using the item id. The formula is as follows:

```
="TY0"&(TEXT([ID]+3200,"#####"))
```

The problem is that the calculation is seeming to take 20 mins or longer to happen. The field will show as "TY032000" until he calculation happens. If the field is changed via settings or SP designer and then changed back to the original formula, the calculation happens with no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer and some more workarounds at: [columns dereferencing in SharePoint's calculated column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986458/columns-dereferencing-in-sharepoints-calculated-column)

It is not 20 minutes, you can wait forever if an Item is never changed.

ID is empty for NEWly created items because the Formulas run BEFORE the Item is written to the List where it gets its ID value.

ID is **not** listed as an available Column when you create a Calculated Column.

As you experience, ID is updated when an Item is changed.
So add a Workflow which updates (anything in) the Item on New Item creation to trigger update of the Formula (now using the correct ID value)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I added a workflow that sets the value of a field on the item to some dummy text, then, deletes it. Still having the issue. I tried also editing a field myself after the workflow has run and the field still won't update.

Comment: Also tried to write the ID to a field on the item via workflow when an item is created. The workflow completed successfully, but the field was blank. So it looks like the ID isn't created until after the workflow runs.

Comment: So the workflow is now writing the Code. I am going to change the field from calculated to single line of text and just have the workflow write the code(using the ID) whenever a new item is created. THANKS!